# Can I import babel-polyfill modules rather than all in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

How can I import some specific modules of babel-polyfill rather than import all ? It seems too huge size for me to import all of it and I just use few of the features of it.

What I want is like following:

```
import "babel-polyfill/symbol";
```

Answer (score 12):

Under the hood, the `babel-polyfill` uses a project called [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) (with some customisations of course). It exposes a [CommonJS API](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#commonjs), so assuming you are transpiling to CommonJS (default behaviour when using [preset-es2015](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/)), you could simply use that instead:

```
// This pollutes the global namespace. May conflict with
// any real Symbol implementations in the future
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
// Namespace-safe Symbol import
import symbol from "core-js/es6/symbol";
```

It's important with this approach that you use a bundler of some sort (Browserify, Webpack, etc), because core-js is made up of a *lot of* smaller modules and may cause a lot of unnecessary HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can import core-js directly if you do not wish to import entire babel-polyfill in order to optimize. Core js can

```
//import 'babel-polyfill';  

//Selective imports in modular pattern
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import 'core-js/fn/promise';
import 'core-js/fn/string/includes';
```